# Why am I receiving a value error

Tags: python, tkinter

The error that I am receiving is `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''` , when I click the Decimal to Binary button.

I also am also getting `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'e'`, when I click the Binary to Decimal button.

Below is all of the code so that you can see where the error is if it is outside of the converting function itself. Any help on what I need to fix and how to fix it would be much appreciated.

```
import Tkinter

def convertDtoB(binary,left):                  
    if(left>0):                                 
        binary+=str(left%2)                     
        return convertDtoB(binary,left//2)      
    else:
        binary = int(binary[::-1])            
        return binary

def convertBtoD(decimal):                    
    answer = 0                                  
    length = len(str(decimal))                  
    decimal2 = str(decimal)[::-1]               
    for i in range(length):
        answer+=int(decimal2[i])*2**i
    return answer

class simpleapp_tk(Tkinter.Tk):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        Tkinter.Tk.__init__(self,parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.initialize()

    def initialize(self):
        self.grid()

        self.entryVariable = Tkinter.StringVar()
        self.entry = Tkinter.Entry(self,textvariable=self.entryVariable)

        self.button1 = Tkinter.Button(self, text="Convert Decimal to Binary", command=lambda: self.OnButtonClick(1))
        self.button1.grid(column=1,row=1)

        self.button2 = Tkinter.Button(self, text="Convert Binary to Decimal", command=lambda: self.OnButtonClick(2))
        self.button2.grid(column=1,row=2)

        self.labelVariable = Tkinter.StringVar()
        label = Tkinter.Label(self,textvariable=self.labelVariable, anchor="center", bg="white")
        label.grid(column=1,row=0,columnspan=2,sticky='')
        self.labelVariable.set("Select a conversion.")

        self.grid_columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
        self.resizable(True,False)
        self.update()
        self.geometry(self.geometry())

    def OnButtonClick2(self, button_id):
        if button_id == 3:
            binaryNumber = convertDtoB("",self.decimalNumber)
            self.labelVariable = Tkinter.StringVar()
            label_2 = Tkinter.Label(self,textvariable=self.labelVariable, anchor="center", bg="white")
            label_2.grid(column=1,row=0,columnspan=2,sticky='')
            self.label_2.set(binaryNumber)
        elif button_id == 4:
            binaryNumber = convertBtoD(self.binaryNumber)
            self.labelVariable = Tkinter.StringVar()
            label_2 = Tkinter.Label(self,textvariable=self.labelVariable, anchor="center", bg="white")
            label_2.grid(column=1,row=0,columnspan=2,sticky='')
            self.label_2.set(binaryNumber)

    def OnButtonClick(self, button_id):
        if button_id == 1:
            self.button1.destroy()
            self.button2.destroy()
            self.entryVariable = Tkinter.StringVar()
            self.entry = Tkinter.Entry(self,textvariable=self.entryVariable)
            self.entry.grid(column=1,row=0,sticky='EW')
            self.decimalNumber = self.entryVariable.set("Enter Decimal Number Here")
            self.entry.focus_set()
            self.entry.selection_range(0, Tkinter.END)

            button3 = Tkinter.Button(self, text="Click here to convert", command=lambda: self.OnButtonClick(3))
            button3.grid(column=1,row=1)

            self.OnButtonClick2(3)

        elif button_id == 2:
            self.button1.destroy()
            self.button2.destroy()
            self.entryVariable = Tkinter.StringVar()
            self.entry = Tkinter.Entry(self,textvariable=self.entryVariable)
            self.entry.grid(column=1,row=0,sticky='EW')
            self.binaryNumber = self.entryVariable.set("Enter Binary Number Here.")
            self.entry.focus_set()
            self.entry.selection_range(0, Tkinter.END)

            button4 = Tkinter.Button(self, text="Click here to convert", command=lambda: self.OnButtonClick(4))
            button4.grid(column=1,row=1)

            self.OnButtonClick2(4)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = simpleapp_tk(None)
    app.title('my application')
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Well you call `binaryNumber = convertDtoB("",self.decimalNumber)` so why are you surprised? You give an empty string into the `binary` argument, and then you try to do `int(binary[::-1])`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There a number of bugs in the code, the primary of this is on lines 65 to 68 and similarly on lines  80 to 83

```
    self.entryVariable = Tkinter.StringVar()
    self.entry = Tkinter.Entry(self,textvariable=self.entryVariable)
    self.entry.grid(column=1,row=0,sticky='EW')
    self.decimalNumber = self.entryVariable.set("Enter Decimal Number Here")
```

here you are setting up the inputbox to use the variable self.entryVariable instead of self.decimalNumber. The set method of the StingVar object is an in-place method and does not return anything useful(it returns none as all inplace methods). Hence the self.decimalNumber variable never actually refers to the StringVar object. Here is the code with this and a few other bugs fixed.. XD

```
def OnButtonClick2(self, button_id):
    if button_id == 3:
        binaryNumber = convertDtoB("",int(self.entryVariable.get()))
        self.labelVariable = Tkinter.StringVar()
        label_2 = Tkinter.Label(self,textvariable=self.labelVariable, anchor="center", bg="white")
        label_2.grid(column=1,row=0,columnspan=2,sticky='')
        self.labelVariable.set(binaryNumber)
    elif button_id == 4:
        binaryNumber = convertBtoD(self.entryVariable.get())
        self.labelVariable = Tkinter.StringVar()
        label_2 = Tkinter.Label(self,textvariable=self.labelVariable, anchor="center", bg="white")
        label_2.grid(column=1,row=0,columnspan=2,sticky='')
        self.labelVariable.set(binaryNumber)

def OnButtonClick(self, button_id):
    if button_id == 1:
        self.button1.destroy()
        self.button2.destroy()
        self.entryVariable = Tkinter.StringVar()
        self.entry = Tkinter.Entry(self,textvariable=self.entryVariable)
        self.entry.grid(column=1,row=0,sticky='EW')
        self.entryVariable.set("Enter Decimal Number Here")
        self.entry.focus_set()
        self.entry.selection_range(0, Tkinter.END)

        button3 = Tkinter.Button(self, text="Click here to convert", command=lambda: self.OnButtonClick2(3))
        button3.grid(column=1,row=1)

    elif button_id == 2:
        self.button1.destroy()
        self.button2.destroy()
        self.entryVariable = Tkinter.StringVar()
        self.entry = Tkinter.Entry(self,textvariable=self.entryVariable)
        self.entry.grid(column=1,row=0,sticky='EW')
        self.entryVariable.set("Enter Binary Number Here.")
        self.entry.focus_set()
        self.entry.selection_range(0, Tkinter.END)

        button4 = Tkinter.Button(self, text="Click here to convert", command=lambda: self.OnButtonClick2(4))
        button4.grid(column=1,row=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider this call

```
binaryNumber = convertDtoB("",self.decimalNumber)
```

This will call `convertDtoB` where the value of `decimal` is an empty string.  This will eventually be passed to `int` and end up evaluating `int('')` resulting in the error you are getting.

You either need to make `convertDtoB` resilient against empty strings or change the calling code to not pass one

Comment: I changed it so that convertDtoB doesn't take the empty string in, but I am now getting the error: local variable 'binary' referenced before assignment